# Datagrid click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, datagrid

I'm trying to raise an alert pop up from vb code behind.  I can get the alert box to pop up but its only after the code has run.  I've tried using 2 separate if statements to evaluate the first one raise javascript function click ok then move on to the second one but either way the code executes while the pop up box is displaying.  Any suggestions or what exactly am I missing?

thanks

Here is the code

```
    Private Sub AssignOwnership(ByVal AccountCode As String)
    Dim dgAssetList As ArrayList = DirectCast(Session("CHECKED_ITEMS"), ArrayList)

    If dgAssetList IsNot Nothing AndAlso dgAssetList.Count > 0 Then
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alert", "alert('transer records?')", True)
    End If

If dgAssetList IsNot Nothing AndAlso dgAssetList.Count > 0 Then
        Dim dInspDate As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
        Dim dNextInspDate As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
        Dim dNextReplDate As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
        Dim dReplDate As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
        Dim dInspFromCalc As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
        Dim dReplFromCalc As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
        Dim dAReplDate As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
End If
```

Comment: I think what you're missing is a clear understanding of client vs. server when writing a web app.  You can't raise an alert (or any other javascript function) from your VB .Net codebehind file.

Comment: I believe i phrased that wrong then.  using the clientscript.registerstartupscript IS calling the javascipt function from the code behind.  What I need for it to do on that alert box is wait until Ok is is clicked then continue on

Comment: You're mistaken.  `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` is simply adding the script to the page.  The script doesn't actually run until the page is rendered in the browser.  A simplified example of the flow looks like this: You have a Web Forms .ASPX page. -> your VB .Net code does stuff to the page (i.e., adds your JavaScript alert) before it is sent to the browser. -> The page is sent to the browser. -> Client-side script (i.e., JavaScript) is run in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment about server-side code vs. client-side.  You will have to put the code you want to run after the alert in a separate method, and call that method from the client via AJAX.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.